# JavaFX can't play audio

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I am working on a music player.  The player works correct on my Windows host, but when I try to run the code on a virtual (VirtualBox) Ubuntu 12 VM I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:511)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:414)
    at musicmaniac.PlayerPane.playSong(PlayerPane.java:142)
    at musicmaniac.PlayerPane.playSelectedSong(PlayerPane.java:180)
    at musicmaniac.SongsPane.lambda$addSongsToVBox$0(SongsPane.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:274)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:118)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:467)
    ... 36 more
```

This is the code that I am running:

```
/**
 * Plays the passed song and queues the next song.
 * @param song The song to be played
 * @param playSong if the song should start playing. False means the song will be paused.
 */
private void playSong(Song song, boolean playSong) {   
    // stop current player
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }


    Media media = new Media(new File(song.getPath()).toURI().toString());
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);

    // Set the song as playing or paused
    if (playSong) {
        mediaPlayer.play();
       Image playImg = new Image(MusicManiac.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/img/pause.png"));
        playButton.setImage(playImg);
    } else {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    // Set the next song to be played
    mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            nextSong();
        }
    });

    songLabel.setText(song.getName() + "  --  " + song.getArtist());
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code or is it the VM/Ubuntu?  BTW I checked and it is running on Java8 so that's not the problem.

Comment: How does the path of a song looks like?

Comment: Is your VM configured to bridge the sound card ? The other sounds are playing in the VM? Also as @StefanSprenger mentioned , could you please double check that your `File(song.getPath()).toURI().toString()` exists

Comment: @StefanSprenger I checked song.getPath() before loading the song and it is a valid path.  Here is an example of what one path looks like: "/home/tyler/Music/Blue Öyster Cult - The Best Of-Don't Fear The Reaper [2000][320 KBPS]/08 Goin' Through The Motions.mp3".

Comment: @AntJavaDev The sound card is configured correctly.  Also I double checked and the path is a valid path.

Comment: I found a fix.  You need to install libavformat.  You can do this by running: sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev